# Which jar or jars are included with JSF Sun Reference Implementation 1.2

Tags: jsf, classloader, ibm-was

I need to package an application with Sun Reference Implementation 1.2 but I cannot have access to productive WAS 8.5 console to set SUN RI 1.2 option, after reading this goo.gl/x0rZto I've learned that DEFAULT implementation for WAS 8.5 is MYFACES 2.0 so I've decided to build my app using SUN RI 1.2 libraries as shared libraries and set classloader to PARENT LAST in order to get the properly JSF version running with my project, but I'm not sure about the jars used by WAS 8.5 as "SUN RI 1.2" option, will it work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to access console to define shared library and classloader anyway. So I'd suggest just to switch JSF settings, rather than including your own implementation. Check [this link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tweb_jsf.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-13-2-33-0-2-3&lang=en) for procedure to switch to Sun RI faces.